# I am getting Null pointer exception when i run my app 2nd time

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
```

This is the line where the exception is pointing to

```
  String tot=avg[i+2];
             total=Float.parseFloat(tot);
```

and

```
 adapter=new VivaAdapter(Attendance.this,gedata());
```

I am recieving data in form of string and then converting it into float  ,but the app runs fine first time but second time it throws exception

I tried to change avg[i+2].trim() but dint worked

App crashes every alternative time

Eception log:

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.rushabh123453.attendancepict, PID: 643
                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:304)
                                                                                          at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
                                                                                          at com.example.rushabh123453.attendancepict.Attendance$Networking1.onPostExecute(Attendance.java:189)
                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Comment: The exception seems pretty clear there;

Comment: what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a null check before parsing into float

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(tot)){
   total=Float.parseFloat(tot);
}
```

Comment: still it is giving same exception,y is it crashing on every alternative attempts only?when we press back button in android does android clear all data ?

Comment: can you share exception log?

Comment: i take userid and password from login screen and gice http post request and response is set to textview now when user press back buttons something happens here?

Comment: i have added exception log

Comment: Code block of line no 189?

Comment: String tot=total[l];

                   float total=Float.parseFloat(tot);

Answer (score 0):

You should check if String is null. You can't call method `trim()` String with null value.

Comment: i am requesting data from html page and data is not empty,it is crashing every alternative time only

Comment: Its tricky,see i have a login that takes user id and password and then post in on html page,and response is stored in string array and showed in textview,now when we press back button and again press login,it crashes with null exception

Comment: Problem solved:- actually i was having a counter which was static , it counts the number of subject and then stores data,so if 12 subjects where there it ws showing 24 eventhough i pressed the back button and hence this error, so here i got a point that static variables store data even if we close that intent